# Install TeamViewer on Ubuntu Gnome 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, teamviewer

I'm trying to install TeamViewer on my computer, but I got the following message when I tried to launch the application :

[image]

Could anyone be able to tell me what do I have to do to fix this problem?

Comment: Install the newest version.

Comment: Could you tell me which version it is? I thought that one was the last version.

Comment: @SandraRoss any luck with this? What were the steps you attempted when installing?